# Mybatis update xml return affected rows count

Tags: mybatis

What's the problem: 
  I hope get a procedure return value which only has a few update sql like below.

```
<update id="updateSingleW11MeetingKeyTmp" parameterType="com.cisco.wbx11.db.meetingmigration.wbx11.migrationmeeting.vo.MappingVO">

    {call
      declare
        begin
            update mtgconference <set> meetingtoolsid= #{w11mkTmp,jdbcType=NUMERIC} </set>
                where siteid=#{w11SiteId,jdbcType=NUMERIC} and hostid=#{w11Uid,jdbcType=NUMERIC} and meetingtoolsid=#{wbxmk,jdbcType=NUMERIC};

            update wbxcalendar <set> confkey= #{w11mkTmp,jdbcType=NUMERIC} </set>
                where siteid=#{w11SiteId,jdbcType=NUMERIC} and hostid=#{w11Uid,jdbcType=NUMERIC} and confkey=#{wbxmk,jdbcType=NUMERIC};

            update wbxconferencekey <set> confkey= #{w11mkTmp,jdbcType=NUMERIC} </set>
                where siteid=#{w11SiteId,jdbcType=NUMERIC} and confkey=#{wbxmk,jdbcType=NUMERIC};
            update WBXREPEATEREXCEPTION set CONFKEY = #{w11mkTmp,jdbcType=NUMERIC}
                where siteid=#{w11SiteId,jdbcType=NUMERIC} and CONFKEY=#{wbxmk,jdbcType=NUMERIC};
        end
    }
</update>
```

I called this with mapper in Java code, but the return is not expected

```
public Integer updateSingleW11MeetingKeyTmp(MappingVO vo) {
    return mapper().updateSingleW11MeetingKeyTmp(vo);
}
```

Comment: What do you want the `mapper().updateSingleW11MeetingKeyTmp(vo)` to return? Total number of updated rows?

Comment: yes. I want check whether update all tables successful by updated rows count.
How can I get it. I'm blocked.

Comment: @tanne222 I don't think this is possible as there is no JDBC API that supports it. You should declare/execute each update separately. Or use procedure.